# Parallax image shows top of image when scrolling down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

With a template I want to use there is a header image that functions as parallax. Works fine, but when you scroll down slowly you see the top of the image at the bottom. Why is that happening?

Example:

On page load everything is fine.

[image]

When I scroll down a little the parallax becomes broken:

[image]

[Page I am talking about](http://www.themenesia.com/themeforest/buildpro/about.html)

It's using the stellar parallax plugin.

Like this:

```
$.stellar({
    horizontalScrolling: false,
    verticalOffset: 0
});
```

Comment: Please share your code instead image/link

Comment: What browser are you using? Everything looks fine on Firefox 50.1.0.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this css:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 992px)
#subheader {  
    background-position: 50% 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: @twan have you try this solution?